# What is member_descriptor and how to access/modify its contents in Python?

Tags: pickle, python-3.6, cpython

Can somebody please explain what **member_descriptor** is and how to access/modify its content from Python interpretor?

Python version = 3.6

```
In [1]: import _pickle

In [2]: _pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table
Out[2]: <member 'dispatch_table' of '_pickle.Pickler' objects>

In [3]: type(_pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table)
Out[3]: member_descriptor
```

I could find only [this](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/133) explaining somewhat about member_descriptor.

Comment: Why do you need this. Are you sure you do not want to import pickle instead of _pickle?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to import _pickle which is a C extension instead of pickle. I need to modify the dispatch_table to register my custom functions for serialization of some types. Eg, I want to override dispatch function for lambdas which is of type `types.FunctionType`.

Answer (score 1):

A `descriptor` is an `object in Python` that defines a `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` method. [Here is a quick howto guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=descriptor#simple-example-a-descriptor-that-returns-a-constant)

This is helpful for eg defining `read-only` values or theoretically also `write-only` or `delete-only` values.

As I understood member descriptors are just special variants of descriptors.
More info can be found in the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismemberdescriptor)
and there you can also find a link to [some C-details](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMemberDef)